# Can the order of Ninja Forms actions be changed?

Tags: php, wordpress, ninja-forms

I'm trying to grab a value from a Ninja Forms submission and then manipulate the success message action to use a WP function based on the value that's been submitted (it's an attachment ID in a hidden field).

However, the Success Message action is firing before the Email action, meaning the variable I'm trying to set that contains the value is being set AFTER the change to the success message is happening.

I need to reverse the order of these two actions, so that the Email action is fired before the Success Message action.

Does anyone know how to do this?

```
function sg_download_nf_success_message($action_settings, $form_id, $action_id, $form_settings) {

    if(isset($action_settings['email_message'])) {

        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->loadHTML($action_settings['email_message']);

        $rows = $doc->getElementsbyTagName('td');
        $count = 0;
        foreach($rows as $row) {
            if($count == 15) {
                $download_id = $row->nodeValue;
            }
            $count++;
        }

    }

    if(isset($action_settings['success_msg'])) {

        global $download_id;

        $action_settings['success_msg'] = str_replace(
            '[download_link]',
            '<a href="'.wp_get_attachment_url($download_id).'" class="btn btn-outline-light">Download your item</a>',
            $action_settings['success_msg']
        );

    }

    return $action_settings;

}
add_filter('ninja_forms_run_action_settings', 'sg_download_nf_success_message', 10, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter to `add_filter` is priority. Maybe split your call into two separate add_filter function with different priority can help?

```php
function sg_download_nf_email_message($action_settings, $form_id, $action_id, $form_settings) {

    if(isset($action_settings['email_message'])) {

        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->loadHTML($action_settings['email_message']);

        $rows = $doc->getElementsbyTagName('td');
        $count = 0;
        foreach($rows as $row) {
            if($count == 15) {
                $download_id = $row->nodeValue;
            }
            $count++;
        }
    }
    return $action_settings;
}
add_filter('ninja_forms_run_action_settings', 'sg_download_nf_email_message', 10, 4);


function sg_download_nf_success_message($action_settings, $form_id, $action_id, $form_settings) {
    if(isset($action_settings['success_msg'])) {

        global $download_id;

        $action_settings['success_msg'] = str_replace(
            '[download_link]',
            '<a href="'.wp_get_attachment_url($download_id).'" class="btn btn-outline-light">Download your item</a>',
            $action_settings['success_msg']
        );
    }
    return $action_settings;
}
add_filter('ninja_forms_run_action_settings', 'sg_download_nf_success_message', 11, 4);
```

Comment: Hey, I had that idea, but it didn't seem to change. Although the two priorities I had were 10 and 20, so maybe 20 wasn't high enough but it didn't seem to change anything, and I Didn't know how high to go. What I actually did to resolve this was instead of showing the link in the success message, I actually created another email action to go to the recipient, and included the link in there. I then created a $GLOBAL variable to pass into the email. I suppose I could actually do the same with the success message too using this method...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ninja_forms_submission_actions` filter to adjust the order/position of the actions.

Unlike `ninja_forms_run_action_settings` which fires before each individual action is executed, `ninja_forms_submission_actions` ***instead fires before any of the actions are executed***.

Within your `ninja_forms_submission_actions` function you receive an `$actions` array of all the actions and `$form_data` variables. The function requires the return of an array of the actions in the order they are to be executed.

So, if you want to execute a given action as the last action you can loop the `$actions` array until you find the action you'd like to reposition. Save a copy of it and remove it from the active array. Then when done looping add it again to the very end. Return that newly updated array and you're all set!

Here's actual code I'm using to ensure the admin email gets fired at the very end of everything (its action ID is 18). I rebuild a copy of the `$actions` array in my example because I wanted/needed the ability to have an original copy of the array for other processing needs.

```
// processed before _ANY_ actions are executed
add_filter( "ninja_forms_submission_actions", "my_ninja_forms_submission_actions", 10, 2 );

function my_ninja_forms_submission_actions($actions, $form_data) {
    
    // will hold my new sequence of actions
    $seq = null;

    // will hold my admin notification action once found in the loop
    $admin_notif_action = null;
    
    // loop the actions
    foreach($actions as $n=>$a) {
            
        if ($a["id"]==18) {

            // if this action is my admin notification then save it to my variable above
            $admin_notif_action = $a;
        }
        else {

            // append to my new sequence all other actions that aren't my admin notification
            $seq[] = $a;
        }
    }

    // finally append as the final item my admin notification and return    
    $seq[] = $admin_notif_action;
    return $seq;
}
```

See also https://developer.ninjaforms.com/codex/submission-processing-hooks/ for official source material from Ninja Forms related to action processing.